# Excel Macro to copy, delete and paste without losing the copy values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to paste some values that I've previously copied, but I'm losing the data as I am clearing the destination cells beforehand.

This is an example of the code:

```
Range("A1:B3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C1:D3").Select
Selection.ClearContents 'At this point the clipboard is cleared
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste 'I get an error here as the clipboard has been cleared
```

Considering that I cannot clear the contents first, is there a way to store the contents of Range("A1:B3") so that I can paste it later?

Answer (score 5):

The obvious answer is: do it in the other order. Also there is no need to use `Select`

```
Range("C1:D3").ClearContents
Range("A1:B3").Copy Range("C1")
```

Furthermore, you should try to fully qualify your ranges. That is, say exactly where those ranges are located.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C1:D3").ClearContents
    .Range("A1:B3").Copy .Range("C1")
End With
```

---

If for some reason (?) you can only clear the contents after... You could store your values in a variable like this

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim v as Variant
    v = .Range("A1:B3").Value
    .Range("C1:D3").ClearContents
    .Range("C1:D3").Value = v
End With
```

Comment: "Considering that I can not clear the contents first"

Comment: Yes, I was trying to simplify the example. The original copy is from another opened file.

Comment: Perfect CallumDA. Store to a variant is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Always happy to help. Don't forget to accept this answer if it did the trick for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get round this by pasting the range somewhere else beforehand.

```
Range("A1:B3").Copy Range("F1")
Range("C1:D3").ClearContents
Range("F1:G3").Cut Range("C1")
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is that it's referencing the cell for the copy data, rather than moving it into the clipboard or into memory. try something like this.

```
dim SelectionSave as string

Range("A1:B3").Select
SelectionSave = activecell.value
Range("C1:D3").Select
Selection.ClearContents 
Range("C1").Select
activecell.value = SelectionSave
```

if you clear the contents of the cell you are referencing an empty cell if you save the contents into memory first you can then move those contents back to the cell after clearing.